# Which tool/editor can list all the functions directly or indirectly call a function?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, notepad++

For example:

```cs
void fooo1()
{
    foo1();
}

void fooo2()
{
    foo2();
}


void foo1()
{
    bar();
}


void foo2()
{
    bar();
}
```

I would like to list all the functions directly/indirectly call function bar, which should be:

> foo1 foo2 fooo1 fooo2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015 you can right click a method definition and chose "View Call Hierarchy" from the context menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ):

[image]

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409859.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Cool! That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I don't know that visual studio has such a great feature